# How can i add a route link to data table column in laravel?

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-blade, yajra-datatable

I have a system that shows the data of all available users of the system with search function. I have done that by using yajra data table package. What I want is if anyone clicks on a row of user that will redirect to that users profile. Here is the controller code

```
public function getUsers(){
    return DataTables::of(User::query()->with('profile'))->make(true);
}

public function index(){
    return view('alumni.list');
}
```

This is the blade code for data table

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#alumniTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('alumni-members') }}",
        columns: [
            { data: 'id' , name: 'id'},
            { data: 'name' , name: 'name'},
            { data: 'email' , name: 'email'},
            { data: 'student_id' , name: 'student_id'},
            { data: 'created_at' , name: 'created_at'},

        ]

    });
});
```

route code:

```
Route::get('/alumni-members', 'AlumniController@index');
Route::get('users','AlumniController@getUsers')->name('alumni-members');
```

Comment: Do you have some errors ?

Comment: No there's no error, I am unable to route users id to the controllers view method

Comment: you didnt pass id to route, you need to add id in route like this : `route('alumni-members', ['id' => $id]`

Answer (score 3):

if you need to add route link column than add column in datatable

```
return Datatables::of(User::query()->with('profile'))
->addColumn('namelink', function ($user) {
    return '<a href="' . route('users.show', $user->id) .'">'.$user->name.'</a>'; 
})
->rawColumns(['namelink'])
->make(true);
```

and also add column in  columns array:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#alumniTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "{{ route('alumni-members') }}",
    columns: [
        { data: 'id' , name: 'id'},
        { data: 'name' , name: 'name'},
        { data: 'email' , name: 'email'},
        { data: 'student_id' , name: 'student_id'},
        { data: 'created_at' , name: 'created_at'},
        {data: 'namelink', name: 'namelink', orderable: false, searchable: 
        false},

    ]

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked but with a slight change.

> return datatables()->of($d)
> ->addColumn('ab_id',function($d){    return "<a href='".**url**('view-detail',$d-
>
> > ab_id)."'>".$d->ab_id."";
> > })   ->rawColumns(['ab_id'])   ->make(true);

instead of the route, I called URL function and it worked